# Cocoapods "framework not found Pods______" after xcode project build when using non-english project names

Tags: xcode, facebook, cordova, ionic3, cocoapods

I am developing an iOS application using ionic v3 framework, I was trying to use cordova-plugin-facebook4@**6.4.0** (that includes Facebook iOS SDK v5.15.0), the plugin requires using Cocoapods dependency manager.

After installing the plugin and creating the iOS build by using `ionic cordova build ios`, I noticed that the pods library named "*Pods______*" in xcode under "Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries" and after building the project using xcode, it shows an error "framework not found Pods______".

The error is because my iOS project name is in Arabic language (not English), which it seems that the pods library named based on the iOS project name, after renaming the project to english name everything worked fine. In ionic the project name sets in "*config.xml*" under name tag.

Is there a way to fix this issue by keeping my iOS project name in Arabic?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that to have the project name in English language (ASCII code) and the display name of the mobile application in a different language you have to write the "*name*" tag in config.xml as following `<name short="نموذج">sample</name>`